# How use API to shorten url using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, api

Is it possible to shorten an url using API ?

```
<form >
  <input type="number" name="field1" value="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
  <input type="button" value="Short">
  <input type="text" name="field2">
</form>
```

I want that the shorten link to be appeared on field2

Please explain in details and which URL shortner site's API to be use.

I want to use it in blogger so please explain only using javascript or other languages which support on blogger. Thanks.

Comment: The better way to ask this would have been to post a wrong answer or some working code, and people might have corrected it. Please have a look at this free Url shortener https://cutt.ly/ and learn its API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use an api to shorten an url. You can use [Bitly's API](https://dev.bitly.com/) to shorten url's. You can still use vanilla js but [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) it good for SEO (but you need to know HTML and React, because is React Framework).

Comment: @hashank-ellareddy Can you share an example?

Comment: Perhaps read the documentation that Shashank has provided?